# Same Doctrine ORM listener for multiple entitites

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

So I will be quick. Let's say you have a `postPersist` event. Can you make the same listener class respond to two different entities if they extend same interface?

```
        <service id="app.entity.my_listener"
                 class="App\Entity\MyListener" lazy="true">
            <tag name="doctrine.orm.entity_listener" entity="App\Entity\Entity1" event="postPersist"/>
            <tag name="doctrine.orm.entity_listener" entity="App\Entity\Entity2" event="postPersist"/>
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
        </service>
```

Keep in mind, both entities extend the same `EntityInterface` so my function signature takes:

```
    public function postPersist(EntityInterface $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $event = null)
```

For "reasons" I can not validate this myself, but wondered if someone else is able to give an answer?

Comment: You could use [instanceof](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) and check if the class uses a certain interface..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use doctrine lifecycle listener :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners

You can make your case work. Since in this case they do not trigger on a specific entity. It is on your hand.
So if the listener should respond to only a specific interface.
As @Bossman said in his comment, you can do :

```
 public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();

    // if this listener only applies to certain entity types,
    // add some code to check the entity type as early as possible
    if (!$entity instanceof EntityInterface) {
        return;
    }

    $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
    // ... do something with the Product entity
}
```